# Mechanize download file

Tags: python, download, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am working with a mechanize script where the goal is to press the buttom "Export to Excel" and download the Excel file.

The problem I am facing is that the direct-url give me a blank page, when I am manually trying to download the file. The only way to download is to click on the buttom. Is that possible to with Mechanize and save the Excel file?

This is the HTML-code:

```
<div class="export-usage float-left">
        <a href="/export-usage/?id=5312022214392713003&amp;from=01.12.2015&amp;to=31.12.2015" class="export-link" target="download_iframe">Export to Excel</a>
        <a class="download-link" target="download_iframe"></a>
        <iframe class="download-iframe" name="download_iframe"></iframe>
```

I have tried to do this, but it didn't work. As mentioned, I have to psysically press to download, direct-link doesn't work:

```
br.retrieve('https://test.com/export-usage/?id=5312022214392713003&from=01.12.2015&to=31.12.2015')
```

Comment: what happens when you do a wget on the url?

Comment: Since I need to authenticate before I can get to the page this is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried to make this request on POSTman and see the request headers? Its hard to reproduce this on my enviroment without knowing the original url. What is this 'br' object?